# Adding only subset of fields during ArcGIS Spatial Join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join, proximity

I am using ArcGis 10.2.

Is there any python script or tool in order to add to my point shapefile only two specific columns I want from my polygon shapefile based on location?

**Spatial Join** adds all columns from both shapefiles to a new shapefile and **Near tool** adds the corresponding FID and DISTANCE but not the columns I want.

Answer (score 4):

The Spatial Join (Analysis) tool has an option of "Field Map of Join Features", you can right click on whichever fields you dont want in the final output and choose delete